# Использование введенного числа haskell

Tags: io, haskell, теория

По всевозможным книгам выдавил из себя кусочек кода :

```
askInt :: IO Int
 askInt =  fmap (fromJust . getInt) $ getLine

getInt :: String -> Maybe Int
getInt n 
    | all isDigit n = Just $ read n
    | otherwise     = Nothing
```

Теперь, в случае если число - число, хочу снять IO, что бы остался чистый Int, для того что бы создать массив определенного размера. Пример:

```
... listArray ((0, 0), (n, n)) $ [0 .. m]
    where n = SOMEVARIABLE - 1
          m = (SOMEVARIABLE)^2-1
```

Но есть то, чего я не могу понять - как можно использовать только число, вызвав ф-цию только один раз в самом начале ?

Answer (score 2):

> если число - число, хочу снять IO, что бы остался чистый Int

Эта фраза была бы корректна, если бы вместо `IO` там было `Maybe`. Убедившись, что в `Maybe Int` действительно лежит `Int`, `Maybe` можно "снять". А `IO` специально придумано так, чтобы его нельзя было "снять" просто так. По-хорошему, нужно пойти читать про монады, но нужный вам код вот:

```
main = do
    i <- askInt
    -- тут i имеет тип Int
    ...
```

Comment: Я и так снимаю Maybe применяя fromJust к getInt. И у меня не возникает вопросов как в пределах одного do использовать то что я получил с клавиатуры. Тут вопрос в том что в пределах этого модуля есть ф-ция которая создает массив, в зависимости от askInt. И получается что мне нужно использовать число, введенное с клавиатуры для опредения размера этого массива

Comment: Эта функция должна принимать `Int`. Вот ей `i` и передайте.